# How to avoid a busy while loop in event-driven Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, polling, java-11, event-driven

I am currently developing my event driven Java software in the following fashion (this is the essence of my main method):

```
while(true) {
    Event event = eventListener.poll();
    if(event != null) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do nothing as usual, but burn CPU time.
    }
}
```

Depending on what I'm building, `eventListener` could be something that's listening to an external websocket, polling a Redis channel for updates, or waiting for a message from another process sitting on the same box (perhaps through UDP/TCP/shm).

My thinking is that this busy loop approach wastes a lot of CPU time when `eventListener` is returning null (which is most of the time), since it just sits there spinning. However, I don't know how else to approach this design, aside from putting a `Thread.sleep` each iteration which is not a great solution.

Ideally I would like to have a method:

```
void run(Event event) {
    // do something
}
```

where `run` is called any time an event hits `eventListener`. If no such event is available, the process should ideally just sitting there idling.

Now, I know there's websocket libraries that can actually do this, what I want to know is how can I build something like this for myself and liberate my CPU from sitting there wasting itself doing nothing?

Comment: The best way to do it is to implement a event passing system where `poll` doesn't need to busy wait. For example if `poll` boils down to `select` calls on some underlying file handles (sockets, named pipes, ...) then you're wasting very little CPU time, because the kernel knows to send your process to sleep while it's waiting for an event.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Is it possible you could elaborate a little, perhaps with a short example? I'm not familiar with an event passing system where poll doesn't need to busy wait. The example I put in my post is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: This is not the level at which you do the wait. You need to (for example) wrap your socket communication in a class and do a non-busy wait on socket read. When you get something on the socket, you generate event (in your wrapper class) which other components of your app can sign up for.

Comment: @ABC: at the end of the day if your `poll` boils down to `InputStream.read()` somewhere then that's already not a busy-wait: your process will not use significant CPU time while it's waiting for new data to arrive. Other mechanisms such as NIO/select allow even more functionality (like reading from multiple sockets at the same time and returning when *any* of them returns data), but that's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [java non-blocking IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29) and may be some library that supports high level communication via java NIO (for example [netty](https://netty.io) which supports NIO style communication for HTTP, websockets and redis among many others).

Here's a short description how NIO works. The thing you are looking is `Selector`. It allows to wait until data on a Channel (which is an abstraction for a file or a network connection etc) is available. This wait (`Selector.select` method) is blocking and the process is resumed by OS when some data is available to be read or the output buffer to write to can get new data.

Schematically the code looks like this:

```
Selector selector = createSelector();
Channel channel = createChannelForSocket();

SelectionKey key = channel.register(selector);

while(true) {

  int readyChannels = selector.select(TIMEOUT);

  if(readyChannels == 0) continue;

  Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

  for(SelectionKey key : selectedKeys) {

    if (key.isReadable()) {
        readDataFromChannel(key.channel())
    } else if (key.isWritable()) {
        writeDataToChannel(key.channel())
    }

  }
}
```

With netty you have more high level code where you define a `Handler` which has a method like `void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)` which is kind of read event listener that you can implement to listen to read events.

netty has a built-in loop that looks similar to the above example but for many event listeners and it propagates those events to particular listeners.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using event-driven architecture at scale. You might want to use a robust "event bus", like Apache Kafka or AWS SNS+SQS. To make it easier, you can use kalium.alkal.io. This will take care of de/serializing from POJO or protobuf objects seamlessly.

```
kalium.on(Event.class, event -> {

   //doSomething with the event
});
```